# Another option for popup selector

Tags: html, popup, jquery, jquerymobile

I have a form which has a disabled field for company name. It has a button, on clicking it, a search window opens up and there we can search the company name and then submit. On Submit,the disabled field is filled in the parent window. But I am not happy with the pop-up window. I need other option using where we can search in the same window. Any suggestions?

Here one of the main conern is security so robots cannot search all my data, that is why I have included a captcha.

Also I need something that can be done on one page instead of going to a pop-up window.

Thanks in advance.

[image: First page]

[image: Search box in pop up window]

[image: Search result]

[image: Copy search result to parent window]

Comment: A screenshot would help here.

Comment: Just added image so that it is more explainable

Comment: Why do you think robots/scripts will be able to grab any of your data[except states/countries etc.]?  If they can,  your form is vulnerable to SQL injections and/or other security risks.  Captcha can be real annoying at times for some people like me,  I am almost never able to read the code in these captcha images .

Comment: I don't want any one taking out the all the companies information whom I am dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery based select list should be a good choice.  For example,  check [this page](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).  Here you will not even need to make the field read-only,  any unmatched values entered in the field will be cleared when the focus of cursor shifts from the field.

Another option would be to make this an input box,  and fetch matching results when the users starts typing.  This idea similar to how Facebook people search works or even Google search does. Clear any unmatched strings from the field on focus out.

**Edit:** OK just noticed the tag `jQuerymobile`.  Select2 plugin may not be the best choice for mobile applications,  but you can find similar plugins or very easily make one yourself. An ajax based search[2nd option] which uses internet may not be the best choice altogether[if not on 3G].

Comment: Thanks.. I have uploaded some images.. do you still have any suggestions